# What to use instead of $rootScope?

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

All my controllers in my application use the `$rootScope` variable `selectedDashboard`. In this example, I set the `$rootScope` variable in `miniCtrl` controller.

I am also using routes and depending which view you are on the other controllers will change the value of `selectedDashboard`. I don't see how I can use a service because I don't want all the controllers to share a set value. The controllers take turns changing the value. So am I using `$rootScope` appropriately?  Or should I be doing something different still?

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardAdmin',[])
  .controller('miniCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

  $scope.selectDashboard = function(e) {
      var newDashboardNum = e.target.attributes.data.value;
      $rootScope.selectedDashboard = newDashboardNum;
  }

});


angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardAdmin',[])
  .controller('otherCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, dummyData) {

  var selectedDashboard = $rootScope.selectedDashboard;
  var data;

  for(var d in dummyData.dashboardsData) {

    if(dummyData.dashboardsData[d].dashboard_number == selectedDashboard) {
        data = dummyData.dashboardsData[d];
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorials around for this. Please try searching before asking questions

Comment: @charlietfl what I am doing differently is setting the $rootScope variable in my first controller, but all the other controller will change the value of the $rootScope.

I don't want all the controllers to share one value that is set in a service because the controllers will be changing them.

Comment: but that's no different than how a service is used but you don't store on $rootScope

Comment: @charlietfl I updated my question. The example link you posted does not help because it is setting the value for one variable in the service that two controllers use...what if the controllers themselves are changing the values?

Comment: they change it on the service....please do a web search and read up on how services are used